# Reducing geodesic distance

Tags: graph-theory, geodesic, image-processing

I read in a paper (on image processing) about a dealing with a graph for some processing tasks. I found something surprising in the text and could not find out that completely.
The authors stated that by doing some operations, it is possible to reduce geodesic distance between nodes. How it is possible to shorten possible shortest paths?

Comment: What were the operations? If you do any of the following you can shorten distances in a graph: add edges, contract edges, lower the 'weight' of edges (in a weighted graph), or identify vertices.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez, OK! Got it, adding edges!!